# How to install python packages correctly on Mac?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I installed `pip` then I wanna install some packages for test,
It seems not work?
what's the problem?

`which python`
`/usr/bin/python`

`which pip`
`/usr/local/bin/pip`

`sudo easy_install pip`

`pip install regex`

error:

`Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/k0/80ltmx5x61xgnp9ld643mdr80000gn/T/pip-build-YKBgHj/regex/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/k0/80ltmx5x61xgnp9ld643mdr80000gn/T/pip-rQ9FJX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/k0/80ltmx5x61xgnp9ld643mdr80000gn/T/pip-build-YKBgHj/regex/`

Comment: what happens when you run this? pip install setuptools --upgrade

Comment: @DomDaFonte long errors `"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/k0/80ltmx5x61xgnp9ld643mdr80000gn/T/pip-TjHw3U-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'")` for parts

Comment: Try to run it as super user (i.e. sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install setuptools -- upgrade)